# What halachic principles are involved in starting the iRobot on Shabbos with a timer?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

What halachic principles are involved in starting the [iRobot](http://www.irobot.co.uk/) on Shabbos with a timer?

Can it be turned on anytime or just at night?

Is it like security cameras in that it is OK to walk by them if you don't want to change anything ("גרמא"). Or is it different because it's a physical entity that you might interact with on purpose?

Comment: I have edited to stop the question being a personal shaaloh and built in a link to the IRobot. Can you clarify why turning it on at night (when it is Shabbos) is different to in the day (or by "night" - did you mean before Shabbos)?

Comment: David, I voted to reopen, now you need to wait to see if more MY users agree to reopen